# how to solve odds against probability questions

Tags: probability

If the probability of winning a game is 0.25,then the odds against winning can be expressed as a:b,in simplest form. The value of a is?

my work:

Answer:
For 25 to 100 odds for winning;

Probability of:
Winning = (0.2) or 20%
Losing = (0.8) or 80%

"Odds for" winning: 1:4
"Odds against" winning: 4:1

so the answer is that a=4

Comment: is this correct

Comment: Wait... no.  Pay attention to what format it *was* given in and what format you want to change it *into*.  The *probability* was $0.25$... that is out of $100$ attempts, $25$ will be wins on average and $75$ will be losses on average.  If we are told the probability is $0.25$ then don't read that as "the odds are $25$ to $100$"... that means something different.

Comment: You started by saying "the probability of winning a game is $0.25$" or $25\%$ and later "Probability of: Winning $= (0.2)$ or $20\%$"

Comment: Your question specifies a $25 \%$ probability of winning, why did you then state your odds of winning are $25:100$? That's wrong. My answer assumes only the first two lines of your question are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not correct.

To convert from probability $p$ to odds $o$ use this formula: $o = \frac p{1-p}$.

In this case, $o = \frac{0.25}{0.75} = \frac 13$.

So odds in favour of event (winning) = $1:3$.

Odds against event (winning) = $3:1$.

So $a=3$.

Note that the fractional representation of odds should be (wherever possible) converted into a ratio representation (using natural numbers with no common factor higher than $1$) as I did in the final steps. The fractional representation is only an intermediate step in computation.

Comment: To emphasize the difference in notation and interpretation, I highly discourage the use of a slash when referring to odds and would only use a colon.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, but the fractional representation is a necessary intermediate in computation. Since odds are generally represented as ratios of natural numbers, specifying the odds as $p:(1-p)$ would not be strictly correct as here that would be $0.25:0.75$, when it should be transformed to $1:3$.